# MPMediaPlaylist - delete a song

Tags: ios, objective-c, itunes-sdk, apple-music, apple-musickit

Is it possible to delete a song from a `MPMediaPlaylist` playlist?

I have the ability to get all the songs in a list:

```
NSArray *songs = [playlist items];
```

Can I loop through this with a given `productID` and delete the item?

Comment: It is not possible to remove/modify items of MPMediaPlaylist until now.  
There is an open radar request already for it: http://www.openradar.me/29314482. You can recreate the playlist after modifying the 'songs' array.

Comment: @firstinq thanks - so is it possible to delete an MPMediaPlaylist ? or would I be stuck with multiple instances of the MPMediaPlaylist?

Comment: @scgough could you solve your problem in the meantime ?

Comment: @Leo I actually went a different route with this in the end so didn't solve the issue above.